# How to test a method that depends on database content?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking

We have methods that return a matching database entry or if no match exists creates the entry and returns that. Using Entity Framework.

```
public Transaction FindOrCreateTransactionByID(string id, DBContext db)
{
    Transaction t = db.Transactions.SingleOrDefault(f => f.TransactionID == id);
    if(t == null)
    {
        t = new Transaction { TransactionID = id };
        db.Transactions.Add(t);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return t;
}
```

There's more to the methods than above, but it should illustrate the scenario.

Should we try to mock the `DBContext`? Pass in `DbSet[Transactions]` and mock that instead? Break the method in to `Find()` and `Create()` instead?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article? Which version of EF are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your code locally to write simple test for a method you mentioned in your question. Here's what I got:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public string TransactionID { get; set; }
}

public class DBContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionService
{
    public Transaction FindOrCreateTransactionByID(string id, DBContext db)
    {
        Transaction t = db.Transactions.SingleOrDefault(f => f.TransactionID == id);
        if (t == null)
        {
            t = new Transaction { TransactionID = id };
            db.Transactions.Add(t);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return t;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class TransactionServiceTests
{
    [Test]
    public void When_transaction_not_found_new_transaction_created()
    {
        const string id = "_id_";

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Transaction>>();

        // setup data
        IQueryable<Transaction> data = new List<Transaction>().AsQueryable();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Transaction>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Transaction>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Transaction>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Transaction>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator);

        var mockContext = new Mock<DBContext>();
        mockContext.SetupGet(x => x.Transactions).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        var service = new TransactionService();
        service.FindOrCreateTransactionByID(id, mockContext.Object);

        mockSet.Verify(
            set => set.Add(It.Is<Transaction>(t => t.TransactionID == id)), 
            Times.Once);
        mockContext.Verify(context => context.SaveChanges(), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

Test has been written using NUnit, but you can replace it with your beloved unit-test framework without any troubles.
The most difficult part was to figure out how to mock Transactions DbSet, so SingleOrDefault invocation would actually work without throwing ArgumentNullException. As you can see, this was accomplished by mocking IQueryable behavior for Transactions. Everything else was really a piece-of-cake.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some test examples for you via [Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/), which makes it easier to mock DBContext:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public string TransactionID { get; set; }
    public string TransactionName { get; set; }
}

public class DBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionService
{
    public Transaction FindOrCreateTransactionByID(string id, DBContext db)
    {
        Transaction t = db.Transactions.SingleOrDefault(f => f.TransactionID == id);
        if (t == null)
        {
            t = new Transaction { TransactionID = id };
            db.Transactions.Add(t);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return t;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest
{
    [TestMethod, Isolated]
    public void TestTransactionExist()
    {
        var service = new TransactionService();         
        string id = "id";
        string name = "name";

        var fakeDb = new DBContext();
        var fakeDbSet = Isolate.Fake.Instance<DbSet<Transaction>>();

        List<Transaction> data = new List<Transaction>()
        {
            new Transaction { TransactionID = id, TransactionName = name }
        };

        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeDb.Transactions).WillReturnCollectionValuesOf(data.AsQueryable());

        Transaction res = service.FindOrCreateTransactionByID(id, fakeDb);

        Assert.AreEqual(name, res.TransactionName);
    }

    [TestMethod, Isolated]
    public void TestNewTransaction()
    {
        var service = new TransactionService();
        string id = "id";

        var fakeDb = new DBContext();
        var fakeDbSet = Isolate.Fake.Instance<DbSet<Transaction>>();

        List<Transaction> data = new List<Transaction>();

        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeDb.Transactions).WillReturnCollectionValuesOf(data.AsQueryable());
        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeDb.Transactions.Add(null)).DoInstead(
        context =>
        {
            data.Add(context.Parameters[0] as Transaction);
            return context.Parameters[0] as Transaction;
        });

        Transaction res = service.FindOrCreateTransactionByID(id, fakeDb);

        Assert.AreEqual(id, res.TransactionID);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!